# How can i add 2 class fields to link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm trying to get this class to also use this custom method I have to check if the link is currently clicked on

```
=link_to 'Contact' , contact_path, :class => 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4 ', :class => is_active?('contact)', :id => "contact"
```

Setting class 2 times has not worked anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `class` twice.

```
:class => is_active? ? 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4' : 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4 contact'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! (Just a note is_active?(param[:action]) so i had to do == 'current'

Answer (score 1):

I thinks that xdazz is right that you can't set class twice. But you could add

```
is_active?('contact)'
```

to the classes :

```
:class => 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4 #{is_active?(contact)}'
```

(assuming that is_active?(contact) results in a boolean value)